# "-" == "-" returns false.. Why?

Tags: ruby, string, irb

[image]

Anybody know whats going on here? why is "-" not found? Try it in IRB.

if you do

```
string = "(( :H – :2B – :3B – :HR )+( 2 * :2B )+( 3 * :3B )+( 4 * :HR ))/ :AB "

string.split(" ")[2] == "-"
```

it returns false as well.

Comment: The title of this question is very misleading.

Comment: Please post code as text, not as a picture. How do you expect us to work with it?

Comment: I changed the title so it's a little more descriptive of the actual question. And there is code posted as text. I wanted to show the irb return value so people didnt just say. No it doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The character you get from `string.split(" ")[2]` is `–`. This may look like a normal hyphen, but it is in fact a different character from the normal hyphen: `-`.

You can see this by getting the ordinal value of each:

```
string.split(" ")[2].ord # => 8211
"-".ord # => 45
```

Therefore, you should be checking for equality with the unicode character `\u2013`:

```
string.split(" ")[2] == "\u2013" # => true
```

Or you can replace all occurrences of `\u2013` with `-`:

```
string.gsub!("\u2013", "-")
string.split(" ")[2] == "-" # => true
```

Comment: Nice Thanks! I'll accept it in a sec. It won't let me for 10 minutes after posting.

Answer (score 0):

They are not equal

```
irb(main):002:0> string.split(" ")[2]
=> "[G–"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing two different dash characters. The normal dash that usually is inputed with the keyboard (ascii character 45) is what you're comparing to, but the text you're parsing has ascii character 8211 (the en dash).

See this http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm.

Indeed, if you simply type `"-" == "-"`, you'll get `true`